# Work and Display a Custom Post Type as a normal Post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions

I've created some Custom Posts for my Wordpress page and I can work fine with them. I can create a new one, edit it and display it in "archive-custom_post_type_name.php" and many more things. I can even use the same category as a normal post.

My huge problem is that I can't display them as a normal post in my website. I want to display mixed between normal posts.

I tryed:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {    
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
         $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'actualizacion', 'notificacion' ) );    
    return $query;
}
```

But nothing happens. I also tryed:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_mi_cpt' );
/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_mi_cpt( $query ) {    
    if ( $query->is_main_query() )
         $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'LISTA_CPT' ) );    
    return $query;
}
```

In my wp-admin I can see my Custom Posts between the normal posts, ut my problem with that snippet is that my webpage then gives me a 404 error.

It's anyway to create Custom Post Types and work with theme as normal posts so I can display all theme mixed in my website?

Thanks!

---EDITED---

I changed my first snippet and now Custom Post Types displays alright in my WP-Admin "Show all posts" page, but not in the website:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'My_Custom_Post_Type_List' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
```

---EDITED 2.0---

Maybe next step is to change the Loop in page.php to display that custom post types in the loop? My loop looks like this:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content','page' ); ?>

            <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
            endif;
            ?>

        <?php
        endwhile;

    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi there! So you *always* want to include your custom posts with other, regular posts? Or you just want to do this on, say, your homepage?

Comment: @MacPrawn always with other regular post, not only in the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think you could apply the [codex example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Include_Custom_Post_Types_in_Search_Results) as is:

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'actualizacion', 'notificacion' ) );
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

I think you were just missing the `!is_admin()` check in there...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes!! That works great but only works when I search something. What I need is to display them automatically in the posts loop after publish a New Custom Post Type.

Comment: Then I'd try and remove the `if ($query->is_search) {` around `$query->set`...

Comment: I just tryed that solution and it's 50% ok. Now I can see my Custom Post Types between WP-Admin "Show all posts" mixed between posts. Perfect!! But now I have to display them as if they were normal posts in my webpage because they don't display yet even with this solution.

Comment: maybe I should change something in the page.php Loop?

Comment: Well, the code I showed you should **not** affect the admin side of things... You say you see all post types when you click on "Posts" in wp-admin? Could it be you did not negate the `is_admin()` check, as in `!is_admin()`? (notice the "!")... That could explain why it works in the back-end, but not in the front-end... You probably do not want the back-end to list your custom posts with the regular ones - that's calling for trouble.

Comment: Yes, now they don't display between normal posts in WP-Admin. But neither in front-page :(

Comment: HI Roberto... Yes indeed: so when you say `is_admin() && ...` you are affecting queries in the admin section of WP. Inversely, if you use `!is_admin() && ...` you are only affecting queries on the front end of your site. As I said, I don't think it's a good idea on the back-end to have one list of posts with many different types of posts in there. I would have to question why you do not want to use one admin menu item per post type? In any case, if you want to give it a try and have a full list of all post types on both the back and front ends, simply use `if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {`